# use of UIscrollview to scroll page and every time showing updates values of selected item

Tags: objective-c

my app is shown with two views table view on the upper side n scrollview on the lower side, now when user selects the item from the table view its corresponding values should be displayed in scrollview. when user scrolls page ,the other values related to selected item should be displayed on second page with newer labels.. and user return back to previous page the content should remain same as they were before scrolling. how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `gotoxy(short int, short int)` in the header file.

And use some coding relating to (up,down,left,arrow) key, just find out the ASCII values of that key.  So, when user click up arrow once, the highlighted part should move upwards using `textbackground(WHITE)` and the scroll page should appear using if statement.

Remember to use `input=getche();` that's the most important part. Don't use `getch();`